# hyperref inconsistent with documentclass{exam}?

Tags: spacing, hyperref, exam

I want to use the hyperref package in my exam paper (for some reason). However, there's a problem with the spacing.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
\begin{oneparchoices}
\choice 1\\
\choice 2
\end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

It looks something like this:

[image]

If I remove the hyperref package, then it looks good:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: According to the documentation of the `exam` class,  the `oneparchoice` environment 'lists all of the choices in a single paragraph[...]'. If you want to display one choice per line, why don't you use the `choices` environment instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print choices in multiple lines, why don't you use the `choices` environment?

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
\begin{choices}
\choice 1
\choice 2
\end{choices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]